# Change screen resolution not working after signing out windows 7,8 C#

Tags: c#-4.0, screen-resolution

I have a small app to change a screen resolution

1. List available windows screen resolution for example (1024x768,
   1680x1050..) -> done
2. Select one resolution then Click "Change resolution" -> done

I use a function

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(
        ref DEVMODE devMode, int flags);
```

Everything works fine. I can easily change from 1680x1050 to 1024x768. But the problem is when I try to sign out then sign in back, Windows changes back to 1680x1050 automatically??? I don't know why

Has anyone faced this problem? And do you have a solution for this issue?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The *flags* value you pass is very important.  Nobody can tell what you use.  Do not expect to be able to make global changes unless your app runs elevated.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I really confuse about flag value and do not know what its meaning... :(